# yum makecache and downloading all installed rpm

Tags: centos, rhel, yum

I basically want a copy of all rpm's of the correct version of what is installed on my server at the moment.  How can that be done?

I have one server that is registered to all the RHEL repositories as well as EPEL and RPMfusion.  The  `/etc/yum.conf` I have `keepcache=1` and this works by keeping all downloaded & installed rpm's when doing a *ym update*.

But I have done a *yum clean all* and all the rpm's that were under the `packages/` subfolders under `/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7Server` are gone.

I was thinking a *yum makecache* might do that but does not, it redoes some metadata whatever giving me a 2.7gb cache folder but the rpm's that I want available under the `packages/` subfolder is still empty.  What's the best or most elegant way of getting all those rpm's back?  An `rpm -qa` lists 2,357 rpm's, I basically want all those.

Comment: Download the lot using `reposync` or selectively download RPMs using `yumdownloader`.

Answer (score 1):

This command should get you the RPMs. Having just run it, it appears a bunch of the RPMs are not in the CentOS vault for some reasons so you might have to manually track them down or enable the right yum repo that has them.

`rpm -qa | xargs -n1 yumdownloader -y --enablerepo='C7*'`

The `--enablerepo='C7*'` part is to enable the repos in `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo`. If you want to just enable all repos installed, it is `--enablerepo='*'`

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to figure out exactly what you want that is different from the output of "rpm -qa".

If you want the actual files, use the output of that command & write a shell script using wget or curl to download all of those files from your favorite repository.

If this is not what you want, please explain in further detail.